# Eclipse's executable file won't run in ubuntu

Tags: eclipse

I just downloaded the eclipse package from the eclipse website in zipped format. I unzipped it in my user directory and set 777 permissions, but double clicking the eclipse executable won't do anything. I tried running the executable file through terminal, but it shows the error:

```
bash: ./eclipse: No such file or directory
```

Then I installed eclipse through Ubuntu software center, which runs successfully. Just the downloaded version doesn't run.

I have installed OpenJDK in Ubuntu 10.10. Can anyone please tell what is wrong with my Eclipse?

Comment: hit `ls` in the path your are, if you see the eclipse there, try `chmod +x eclipse` and `./eclipse`, there also might be something wrong with the java version of your system try `java --version` and paste the output.

Comment: I verified. The file is there and it is set as executable.

java --version gave the following:- "Could not create the Java virtual machine."

However, 'java -version' gave this:- "java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9) (6b20-1.9-0ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b16, mixed mode)". I'm running OpenJDK.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about you mentioning "zipped format" - are you 100% sure you downloaded Linux version? Linux version is .tar.gz, and even has executable bit set on the 'eclipse' binary, so no chmod is necessary.

Comment: @Sergey Yes, I downloaded the Linux version in a tarball (tar.gz)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My OS was actually 64 bit version. And the Eclipse package I downloaded was 32 bit. It seems stupid, but usually 32 bit softwares run without any problem in 64 bit operating systems. So I didn't pay much attention there.

I downloaded the 64 bit version of Eclipse and it works fine.

Thanks @Sergey for the time and patience.

Answer (score 3):

The message from bash suggests that there is no such file - I suggest you to double-check that you're in the correct directory, that execute bit is indeed set etc.

Try invoking it like this:

```
cd ~/folder/where/you/unpacked-it
chmod +x ./eclipse
./eclipse
```

Actually, even changing permissions is not necessary - the binary already had executable bit set.

Comment: 'Allow executing file as program' option is checked. I tried bash eclipse as you said. Then it showed "eclipse: eclipse: cannot execute binary file". Any idea? :(

Comment: Yeah, Ubuntu's 'eclipse' command is a bash script while in the archive it is an ELF executable, so bash is not relevant here.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem about the Eclipse binary and started to follow the suggestions of this thread. I checked the OS and kernel versions, and tried to change the file permissions.
After executing the `chmod` command I checked with `ls -l` and the output surprised me: nothing was changed.

After some more tries and a minute to think, I figure out the problem: The eclipse folder was in a directory outside the OS drive. It was on a NTFS drive, and I hadn't any special permission on it.

The easy solution was to take it back to the home/opt folder. But I'm still interested in a solution that enables the execution inside a NTFS partition.